# Conclusion of Hurewicz for $H_3$ without vanishing fundamental group?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology

Fix a space $X$, which I want to assume is a manifold. Under the assumption of simple-connectivity, Hurewicz's theorem tells us that
$$
\pi_3(X)\to H_3(X,\mathbb{Z})\qquad (*)
$$
is surjective, hence that every homology class is represented by a map $S^3\to X$. There is lots of hard work gone into worrying when homology classes are represented by embedded submanifolds, but that is not what I'm interested in here. What I want to know is:

> Are there are nontrivial examples of manifolds $X$ with $(*)$
> surjective, but with infinite $\pi_1(X)$?

I don't need the case when $\pi_1$ is finite, since I have a different proof that doesn't need this more subtle property.

An equivalent question is asking whether $H_3(\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z})\to H_3(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective, for $\tilde{X}$ the universal covering space. Since $\pi_1(X)$ is nontrivial, then questions about the Eilenberg–Moore spectral sequence become more subtle, but I'm only looking at such a low-dimensional group that maybe things are not so bad (I don't really understand the EM spectral sequence, even relative to my background knowledge of spectral sequences, so I don't quite know how to start extracting information from that).

**Added:** I was interested to know if there are general hypothesis that allow me to conclude $(\ast)$ is onto, but given a [comment below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389703/conclusion-of-hurewicz-for-h-3-without-vanishing-fundamental-group/389705#comment992815_389703) by user51223, I think all I care about is the weaker statement that
$$
\pi_3(X)\to H_3(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H_3(X,\mathbb{Z})/\text{torsion} \qquad (**)
$$
is surjective. So:

> Are there general conditions that guarantee this weaker statement is
> true?

Comment: Does "nontrivial" mean $H_3(X)$ is nontrivial?  If so, sure.  Take $S^1 \vee S^3$, you can thicken that up to a manifold with boundary or "thicken" it to a closed manifold, provided it's suitably high-dimensional.

Comment: Could you give a reference for your version of Hurewicz's theorem? For me it says that $\pi _2(X)\cong H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, but nothing about the next degree.

Comment: As a CW-complex, the nontrivial attaching maps are those attached to the 2-cell. If every three dimensional homologous class is spherical then it implies that the 3-skeleton of your space is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of its 2-skeleton and a wedge of 3-spheres. The example above is of this type. You see that the fundamental group does not play any role in getting this splitting, at least what I can see.

Comment: @abx You may look at Mosher and Tangora for the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: @user51223: Thank you, but could you give a page number? I just find the standard Hurewicz theorem in Mosher-Tangora.

Comment: @abx Wikipedia cites page 390 of Hatcher's book, but it's left there as an exercise.

Comment: Look at the last paragraph of page 2 and continue to page 3. This is numbering in the old print which I use.

Comment: I think you can use the above to show that any copy of integers in $H^3$ gives rise to spherical classes!

Comment: @user51223 hmm, that's interesting. Can you say more? Might it be the case that $\pi_3(X) \to H_3(X,\mathbb{Z}) / (torsion)$ is surjective, possibly under mild assumptions?

Comment: OK, thanks to both of you! I am fine with Hatcher's exercise.

Comment: @theHigherGeometer: regarding your added question, there are at least lots of examples.  In fact, Kervaire showed that any finitely-presented group can be
realized as the fundamental group of a closed, oriented smooth 4-manifold. So, for any finitely-presented, infinite group $G$ with finite abelianization there is a closed, oriented $4$-manifold $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=G$. For such a manifold, $H_1(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$ is a torsion group, and so the same is true for $H^3(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi oh, good point! That's a lovely class of examples.

Comment: Also, by the argument of my answer. If $X$ is any space with $H: \pi_{3}(X) \rightarrow H_{3}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ surjective then $X \times S^1$ also satisfies this condition. So combining with Francesco Polizzi's answer you can get $\pi_{1}(X)$ to be almost anything whilst making $b_{3}(X)$ arbitrarily large. So there will be almost no restriction on the algebraic invariants of $X$

Comment: All these examples are good, but I'm not yet seeing any general topological conditions that imply subjectivity :-)

Comment: I have actually started to worry about my last comment. On the other hand, say $\pi_2X\simeq 0$. Then, if such a condition is possible in your case, any element of $H_3(X;\mathbb{Z})$ must be spherical, right?! This implies that the $3$-skeleton splits as the wedge of $3$-spheres and the $2$-skeleton. Unless, you wish for some homological condition on $H_2$.

Comment: @user51223 I couldn't say! The reason I'm asking this is that I don't know enough nitty-gritty about the sorts of calculations one does here. I've only seen either high-powered spectral sequence results (and really scary papers on exotic notions of convergence), or there are low-dimensional topology arguments like Ian's below, that I'm completely unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 7):

Take $M = S^1 \times S^3$ . Then $\tilde{M} = \mathbb{R} \times S^3$ and clearly $\pi_{*} : H_{3}(\tilde{M},\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H_{3}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective, since it maps the $3$-cycle $\{x\} \times S^3$ to the generator ${[x]} \times S^3$.

Answer (score 6):

For closed 3-manifolds, this holds iff it is the 3-sphere. If the fundamental group of a closed 3-manifold $X$ is infinite, then $H_3({\tilde X})$ is trivial.  If $\pi_1(X)$ is finite, then $\tilde{X}\cong S^3$, and $H_3(\tilde{X})\cong \pi_3(\tilde{X})$. So the map $\pi_3(X) \to H_3(X)$ will have range a subgroup of index $|\pi_1(X)|$.

For a closed 4-manifold $X$, $H_3({\tilde X})$ will be torsion-free. If it’s  non-trivial, then $\pi_1 X$ will have more than one end, and hence by [Stallings’ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups?wprov=sfti1) $\pi_1 X$ will split over a finite group. Take a maximal splitting of $\pi_1 X$ as a [graph of groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_groups) with finite edge groups. Then if the vertex groups have $H^1( ;\mathbb{Q})=0$, then your condition (*) should hold with rational coefficients. In fact I think this is also necessary, but one might have to analyze Stallings’ proof to show this.  Equivalently, the map from the manifold to the graph defining the graph of groups should induce a surjection on $H^1( ; \mathbb{Z})$ from the graph to the manifold. As in the 3-manifold case, I’m not sure that this can hold with integral coefficients when the edge groups of the graph of groups are non-trivial finite groups (in this case one might only hit a finite-index subgroup of $H_3(X)$).  So I’m guessing that a necessary and sufficient condition is that the manifold is a connect sum of a manifold $X$ with $H_3(X)=0$ and $\#^k (S^1\times S^3)$ (or the twisted version $S^1\tilde{\times} S^3$ if non-orientable manifolds are included).

Answer (score 5):

Let $X$ be a [fake projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane). It is a quotient of the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$ by a co-compact subgroup of automorphisms, hence $\pi_1(X)$ is infinite and non-abelian.

By Poincaré duality, we have $H^4(X, \mathbb{Z})=H_0(X, \, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and so, by the Universal Coefficient Theorem, the torsion part of $H_3(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes.

Since a fake projective plane has the same Betti numbers of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$, it follows $H_3(X, \, \mathbb{Z})=0$ and so your Hurewicz map $(\ast)$ is automatically surjective.

**Comment on the added question.** There are at least lots of examples. In fact, Kervaire showed that any finitely-presented group can be realized as the fundamental group of a closed, oriented smooth $4$-manifold. So, for any finitely-presented, infinite group $G$ with finite abelianization, there is a closed, oriented $4$-manifold $$ with $\pi_1(X)=G$. For such a manifold, $H_1(, \, \mathbb{Z})$ is a torsion group, so the same is true for $H_3(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$ and subsequently $(**)$ is automatically surjective.

Comment: Heh, ironically, that also rules out the interesting behavior I was hoping to see! But thanks for the example.